# band.ReadAsArray returning "1e+37" in gdal

Tags: python, gis, gdal, qgis

I have a grd file. With qgis tool info it shows like this:

[image]

I am creating a script to read raster band:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import osr

filename=r'C:\temp\Myfile.grd'
ds = gdal.Open(filename)
x = 0 # origin coordinate
y = 0 # origin coordinate
for b in range(ds.RasterCount):
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(b+1)
    print("band" + str(b+1))
    array = band.ReadAsArray(x,y,1,1)
    print(array)
```

Script output below:

[image]

I am wondering why band4 returns "1e+37", instead of null or no value.
Can anyone tell me how to get null or an empty string here?

Comment: Try print `band.nodata` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out, it was masked array for no data value.
below code works to remove it.

```
    array = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 1, 1) # origin lat lon
    value = array[0, 0]
    if value == ds.GetRasterBand(4).GetNoDataValue():
        value = "No Data"
```